# DeviceIoControl returning false

Tags: c#, interop, hardware

In my C# code,DeviceIoControl is returning false,the handle is correct

```
DeviceIoControl(deviceHandle,
  IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
  IntPtr.Zero,
  0,
  OutBuffPtr,//&psdn,
  OutBuffSize,
  ref dwBytesReturned,
   IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of data here to go on, but [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error(VS.80).aspx) should give you more specific error information.

Answer (score 0):

I did try to use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() which returned 1, according to MSDN it means incorrect function.
In the code I am trying to get the device number passing Intptr to buffer of size STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER (which is 12 bytes) from function DeviceIoControl in kernel32.dll.

I've hit a dead end.